# Numeric ordering on varchar based co-related subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

let me say that i've a table with some generic-data-holder columns (so it seems developer of the original code selected to use string type). These columns can hold all numerics, alphanumerics or a mix of them.

Let me say i've a co-related subquery like;

```
SOME_CORELATED_QUERY=(SOME SELECT SQL)
```

and let's say that i've an order by clause;

```
order by ID,SOME_CORELATED_QUERY
```

now as these fields are all varchar based, i can't get them numerically sorted by default.

I can try this for my co-related subquery;

```
SOME_CORELATED_QUERY=cast((SOME SELECT SQL) as int)
```

but the problem with above is that, not all my data is numeric and i'll get an error;

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '304L' to data type int.
```

So i found a solution [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81901) which basicly uses spaces which is viable for my problem but the problem is that i can't apply it to co-related subquery.

If i try to apply it on my table column ID, it all works okay;

```
order by space(50-len(ID))+ID, SOME_CORELATED_QUERY
```

but that doesn't work as a solution because i need a numeric sort on my SOME_CORELATED_QUERY. I try it like;

```
order by space(50-len(SOME_CORELATED_QUERY))+SOME_CORELATED_QUERY
```

but i get an error message because somewhat my co-related subquery is not recognized by SQL functions like space,cast, convert etc:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Invalid column name 'SOME_CORELATED_QUERY'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Invalid column name 'SOME_CORELATED_QUERY'.
```

So basically i need way to use SQL function space,cast,convert on my co-related subquery on sort-time.

Note: Changing the database layout, field-type is not possible as the layout is hard-coded on the program i use, which i'm just creating SQL based reports for user.

- I'm also working on mssql2005.

Update: Thanks to Brad, i updated the question text to use 'co-related subqueries' as it was a better description than virtual columns.

Update2: Here's the full-sql as it's asked for;

```
select ID, S.STOCK_ID ,S.STOCK_CODE,S.STOK_SHORT_NAME,S.UNIT1_NAME UNIT_NAME,

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME1=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_1),
  PROPERTY_NAME1=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT, STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY1_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME2=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_2),
  PROPERTY_NAME2=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY2_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME3=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_3),
  PROPERTY_NAME3=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY3_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME4=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES  where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_4),
  PROPERTY_NAME4=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY4_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME5=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_5),
  PROPERTY_NAME5=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY5_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME6=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_6),
  PROPERTY_NAME6=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY6_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME7=(Select PROPERTY_VALUE from STOCK_PROPERTY_VALUES where  PROPERTY_VALUE_ID=a.PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_7),
  PROPERTY_NAME7=(Select PROPERTY_NAME from STOCK_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS SOT,STOCK_PROPERTY_TEMPLATES SOS where SOS.PROPERTY7_ID=SOT.PROPERTY_ID and SOS.ID=a.ID),

  isnull(SUM(case IN_OUT when 1 then UNIT1_VALUE else 0 end),0) IN_VALUE,
  isnull(SUM(case IN_OUT when 2 then UNIT1_VALUE else 0 end),0) OUT_VALUE

    from STOCK_PROPERTY_DETAILS a, STOCK b, STOCK_TRANSACTION_ROWS DHS, STOCK S, WAREHOUSE D 

    where a.STOCK_ID=b.STOCK_ID   and  b.STOCK_ID *= DHS.SHD_ID   and  DHS.SHD = 1 and ID>0 and B.UPPER_STOCK_ID=S.STOCK_ID and D.WAREHOUSE_ID*=DHS.WAREHOUSE_ID

    group by S.STOCK_ID ,S.STOCK_CODE,S.STOK_SHORT_NAME,S.UNIT1_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_1,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_2,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_3,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_4,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_5,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_6,PROPERTY_VALUE_ID_7,ID

    having 1=1 and ((isnull(SUM(case IN_OUT when 1 then UNIT1_VALUE else 0 end),0)-isnull(SUM(case IN_OUT when 2 then UNIT1_VALUE else 0 end),0)<>0 /*##ZERO#*/) or (not(1=1 /*##ZERO#*/)))

    order by   ID,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME1,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME2,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME3,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME4,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME5,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME6,PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME7
```

And i want to sort on PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME1, PROPERTY_VALUE_NAME2 and so..

Comment: Just FYI: those "virtual columns" I believe are called "co-related subqueries"

Comment: If you can post an actual sample of the query, it'd help a lot. (People often rename their object to "MyTable" and "Col1, Col2", and the like to anonymize their work.)

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code, I don't even know where to start. First do not use the implied left join (the one withthe asterisk). It will not give correct results reliably as SQL server sometimes thinks it's a left join and sometimes a cross join. This is true as far back as SQL Server 2000 and this syntax is deprecated. It doesn't work correctly, so don't use it. You should not be using implied joins anyway, ever. Next, those correlated subqueries are performance killers and should be replaced with joins. They run row by row and are almost never a good idea to use.

Comment: yes i understand the code is quite error-prone but as i stated it's not the code i developed but supplied by the "programs" developers. I'm just looking for a quick-fix to get things sorted. Still i'll be taking your suggestions in consideration and i can't find a quick-fix for numerical sorting, i'll go for a complete re-implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it as I don't have an instance to hand but if it will allow you to use a case statement on it something like this may work

```
order by
   case 
      when isnumeric(columnname) then cast(columnname as int) 
      else -1 
   end,
   columnname
```

Hopefully this would do it in two sorts, the first sorting numeric values in numeric order and lumping the alpha stuff in a group at -1 which would then get sorted by alpha by our second part

Answer (score 0):

For numeric ordering on character data use `ORDER BY LEN(columnName), columnName`.